# Truncar decimal y pasarlo a entero

Tags: python

Por ejemplo tengo este decimal `2.344`, quiero que quede así `23` (se deja un decimal y luego se quita el `.`

Actualmente realizo esto, mi duda es si hay una mejor forma de realizarla.

```
a = 2.3444

# Trunco el float a un decimal
b = round(a, 1)

# Convierto a string y le quito el punto
c = str(b).replace(".", "")

# Convierto a int
resultado = int(c)

print(resultado)
```

Salida: `23`

Reitero, funciona correctamente tan solo me gustaría ver si hay una mejor forma de realizarlo.

Comment: Multiplica x10 y luego conviertes a entero

Comment: @Christian Wow, como no lo pensé jajaja

Comment: a = int(a * 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de forma fácil y sencilla, sin mucha cosa

```
a = 2.344
resultado = int(a*10)
print(resultado)
#salida-> 23
```

Answer (score 2):

Eso es muy sencillo se hace con la función `round()`.
Código:

```
numero=9.125
print(int(numero*10))
```

Solucion:

```
91
```

[Enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp)

Comment: directamente puedes hacer `round(numero*10)`, si no recibe otro parámetro solo deja la parte entera.